# How to load bootstrap.js, jQuery and other modules in Angular2 app using SystemJS

Tags: javascript, npm, systemjs

I'm new to angular2, npm and systemjs and I can't figure out how to load and use downloaded node_modules. Let's say I want to load first jQuery and then bootstrap. I modified my systemjs but there are some errors...

**Errors:**

> (index):21 Error: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires
>   jQuery(…)(anonymous function) @ (index):21ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @
>   zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 (index):20 Error: ReferenceError: module is not defined(…)

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
      System.import('jQuery').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
      System.import('bootstrap').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <!--<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'jQuery':                     'node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js',
    'bootstrap':                  'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this)
```

;

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @phip1611

Comment: i would love to take the challenge @JagadeeshGovindaraj :-) give me sometime!

Comment: take your time @MrJSingh. i am wating.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj i have post an answer with working solution if you want i can provide the source code as well :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. I also had the problem that I didn't installed jQuery but jQuery Node. Due to I'm new to all of this I had no clue there is a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you can load jquery and bootstrap with systemjs
#

### installation

```
npm install --save-dev bootstrap jquery
```

### Adding main files in systemjs.config.js

```
'bootstrap':                  'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'jquery':                     'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```

### Using it in your project in main.ts

```
import "jquery";
import  "bootstrap";
```

### That's it you have jquery and bootstrap in your build

### [Source code](https://bitbucket.org/jorawarsingh/angular2-systemjs)

Comment: any example i did not get what you try to say.where can i put import statement ,i am new to angular 2.

Comment: you can put in main.ts to include it in your whole project

Comment: And now you placed bounty on this question and I would appreciate if you can reward me 

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/precisesoftware.in/file/d/0BwrHgOWZuw8tSTJ2bElfdW9zelk/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: TMRW I WILL REWARD TO YOU